# MySqlException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save multiple data to my database with this code:

```
            repNo = MainForm.StaffMixname.Text.Substring(0, 3) & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
            MetroGrid5.DataSource = Nothing
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            Dim Query As String = "SELECT ci.seq_id, CONCAT(ci.lastname, ci.firstname) AS fullname, ci.amountApplied, ci.province, co.kind, co.specifications, co.regOwner, co.location FROM clientinformation ci LEFT JOIN collateraloffered co ON ci.seq_id=co.seq_id WHERE co.kind IS NOT NULL AND ci.province = '" & MetroComboBox8.Text & "' AND ci.seq_id BETWEEN '" & convertedstrFrom.ToString("yyMMdd") & "%' AND '" & convertedstrTo.ToString("yyMMdd") & "%'"
            Dim fetch As New MySqlDataAdapter(Query, connect)
            fetch.Fill(ds, "collateral")
            MetroGrid5.DataSource = ds.Tables("collateral")
            If MetroGrid5.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim cm As New MySqlCommand

                With cm
                    .Connection = connect
                    For i As Integer = 0 To MetroGrid5.RowCount - 1
                        .CommandText = _
                            "INSERT INTO collateralrpt Values('" & repNo & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("seq_id").Value & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("fullname").Value & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("amountApplied").Value & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("kind").Value & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("specifications").Value & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("regOwner").Value & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("location").Value & _
                            "', '" & MetroGrid5.Rows(i).Cells("province").Value & "')"
                        .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Next
                End With
                cm.Dispose()
                cm = Nothing
                With connect
                    .Close()
                    .Dispose()
                End With
            Else
                MsgBox("No Data!")
            End If
```

but unfortunately It shows MySqlException Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
Is there any mistake with the code above? thanks in advance.

Comment: How many columns does `collateralrpt` have? Is it more/less than 9?

Comment: Of course there's a mistake and the error message is telling you what it is. You have provided a number of values and that does not match the number of columns. Either provide the correct number of values for the number of columns that exist or specify what columns you actually want to populate. In fact, do the latter regardless. The fact that you're having this issue and need to ask for help with it shows why you should.

Comment: There are all sorts of other issues with your code too. For a start, you should not be looping through the rows of the grid to get data to save one record at a time. You've got a `DataTable` that already contains all the data so use a `MySqlDataAdapter` to save it all in a single batch. You can even use the same data adapter that you already have, creating your own `InsertCommand`. You would need to set `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `False`, so that all the `RowStates` remain `Added` and the `DataRows` are ready to be inserted.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve data from one table(s) and insert into another, just use a single data adapter. You can even do so if the tables are in a different database - you just need a different connection for the `SelectCommand` and `InsertCommand`. Only a single connection is required for a single database though. E.g.

```vb
Dim selectSql = "SELECT Column1A, Column1B FROM Table1"
Dim insertSql = "INSERT INTO Table2
                 (
                     Column2A,
                     Column2B
                 )
                 VALUES
                 (
                     @Column2A,
                     @Column2B
                 )"

Using connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"),
      insertCommand As New MySqlCommand(insertSql, connection),
      adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(selectSql, connection) With {.InsertCommand = insertCommand, .AcceptChangesDuringFill = False}
    With insertCommand.Parameters
        .Add("@Column2A", MySqlDbType.Int, 0, "Column1A")
        .Add("@Column2B", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Column1B")
    End With

    Dim table As New DataTable

    connection.Open()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    adapter.Update(table)
End Using
```

There are a few things to note here.

1. I wrote the SQL code using a single, multiline literal. That is far
   more readable that concatenating every line.
2. I used parameters. That prevents numerous issues that have been
   written about ad nauseum so I won't go into it here.
3. There's no grid control involved here. You can add one and bind the `DataTable` after calling `Fill` but that is only so you can see the data. It has nothing to do with the actual code of retrieving and saving.
4. The connection is opened explicitly. You can normally let a `Fill` or `Update` call open and close the connection implicitly but, in this case, we want to perform both operations and closing and reopening the connection in between is an unnecessary overhead.
5. The disposable objects are created with a `Using` statement, which means they will be implicitly disposed at the end of the block. That inclides closing the connection.
6. The `AcceptChangesDuringFill` property of the data adapter is set to `True` so that all `RowStates` are left as `Added` so that all `DataRows` are ready to be inserted.